# Package needed: beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp. It's a dependency for the ROS publisher and subscriber tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In publisher and subscriber ROS tutorials this package(beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp) is used as a dependency but I couldn't find it. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251364/please-provide-me-this-package:-beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp.-this-package-is-used-as-a-dependency-in-the-publisher-and-subscriber-ros-tutorials./) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dependency on `beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp` referred to in the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) is a cmake target; not a complete package.

That target is created by the `generate_messages` command in the CMakeLists.txt, and the target name is based on the package name (declared with the `package()` command at the top of the CMakeLists.txt).

You should check that your package name matches the package name in the tutorial, and that the message generation code is present in your CMakeLists.txt.

If you're still have trouble after that, please **edit your question** to include your full CMakeLists.txt and the full error message.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace it by `add_dependencies(target ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})`, It works well , too. It could be more easy to understand :D

---

Originally posted by [kevinssh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32175/kevinssh/) with karma: 31 on 2017-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3